# Graph send mail with attachment

Tags: powershell, graph

I'm trying to send a e-mail with attachment with powershell, as soon as I add in the attachment, I get a 400 Bad Request error, while it works find without attachment. Hope someone has a clue...

Part added:

```
"attachments": [
              {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                "name": "attachment.txt",
                "contentType": "text/plain",
                "contentBytes": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
              }
            ]
```

Full request:

```
    $Subject = "Subject2"
    $Message = "Message2"
    $Recipient = "testemailaddress"
    $SaveToSentItems = $false
        $Request=@"
        {
          "Message": {
            "Subject": $(Escape-StringToJson $Subject),
            "Body": {
                "ContentType": "HTML",
                "Content": $(Escape-StringToJson $Message)
            },
            "ToRecipients": [
              {
                "EmailAddress": {
                  "Address": "$Recipient"
                }
              }
            ],
            "attachments": [
              {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                "name": "attachment.txt",
                "contentType": "text/plain",
                "contentBytes": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
              }
            ]
          },
          "SaveToSentItems": "$(if($SaveToSentItems){"true"}else{"false"})"
        } 
"@

        # Convert to UTF-8 bytes
        $Request_bytes = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.getBytes($Request)
    
        $headers = @{
            "Authorization" = "Bearer $($attributes.EXO)"
            "Accept" = "text/*, multipart/mixed, application/xml, application/json; odata.metadata=none"
            "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            "X-AnchorMailbox" = (Read-AADIntAccesstoken $attributes.EXO).upn
            "Prefer" = 'exchange.behavior="ActivityAccess"'
        }
    
        $url="https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail"    

        Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing -Uri $Url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $Request_bytes
```

Error:

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:47 char:1

- Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing -Uri $Url -Method Post -Headers $h ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for send attachs in mails with ms graph in powershell

```
    $attach = "C:\file.pdf"
    $fileName = (Get-Item -Path $attach).Name
    $base64string = [Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($attach))
            $message = '{
        "message": {
        "subject": "subject",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "HTML",
            "content": "'+$body+'"
        },
        "importance": "high",
        "toRecipients": [
            {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "'+$mail+'"
            }
            }
        ],
        "attachments": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                "name": "'+$fileName+'",
                "contentType": "text/plain",
                "contentBytes": "'+$base64string+'"
            }
        ],
        },
        "saveToSentItems": "true"
    }'
    
    $URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/sendMail"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URL -Headers $headers -Body $message
```

Convert to Base64 string before insert in the request.

I guess you have your own "body"!
Regards.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work here, what are your headers like?

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.
At line:33 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URL -Headers @{Authorization ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: Hi @H1dden69 , sory i though you had that already (Azure). this is an example how i use:
$tokenBody = @{ #Your creds from Azure!!
    Grant_Type = 'client_credentials'
    scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    client_id = $yourAppClientId
    client_secret = $yourAppClientSecret
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/$yourAzureTenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token' -Method POST -body $tokenBody
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($token.access_token"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

Hope it works like a charm!! Regards